# How to Compare a Substring to a Normal White Space in Java

Tags: java, string, compare, substring, whitespace

Sorry if this seems like a silly question, but I cannot figure out how to compare a substring from user input in Java to a white space. In my program, I use

```
      Input.getString()
```

which is not usual, but Input.class is used to receive input from a user. Here is my program:

```
public class Project1
{
static String E [] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", " " };
static String M [] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----", "|" };

public String input[];
public String output[];
static String TranslationType;
static boolean Bool;
static String TextToTranslate;
static int i;
static int SectionOfString;
static StringBuffer emcStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
static StringBuffer mceStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
static String emc = "English-MorseCode";
static String mce = "MorseCode-English";
static StringBuffer MorseCodeLetter = new StringBuffer();
static String emcString;
static String mceString;
static String space = " ";

public static void main( String [] args )
{
    if ( E.length != M.length )
    {
        System.out.println( "Error" );
    }
    TranslationType = Input.getString( "Please choose a method of translation (\"English-MorseCode\" or \"MorseCode-English\") " );
    if ( TranslationType.equals( "English-MorseCode" ) )
    {
        Bool = true;
        System.out.println( TranslationType );
    }
    else if( TranslationType.equals( "MorseCode-English" ) )
    {
        Bool = false;
        System.out.println( TranslationType );
    }

    while ( !TranslationType.equals( emc ) && !TranslationType.equals( mce ) )
    {
        System.out.println( "Error: \"" + TranslationType + "\" is not a valid response.");
        TranslationType = Input.getString( "Please choose a method of translation (\"English-MorseCode\" or \"MorseCode-English\") " );
        if ( TranslationType.equals( "English-MorseCode" ) )
        {
            Bool = true;
            System.out.println( TranslationType );
        }
        else if( TranslationType.equals( "MorseCode-English" ) )
        {
            Bool = false;
            System.out.println( TranslationType );
        }
    }
    TextToTranslate = Input.getString( "What would you like to translate?" );
    TextToTranslate = TextToTranslate.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println( TextToTranslate );
    if ( Bool == true )
    {
        for ( SectionOfString = 0; SectionOfString < TextToTranslate.length(); SectionOfString++ )
        {
            for ( i = 0; i < E.length; i++ )
            {
                if ( TextToTranslate.substring( SectionOfString, SectionOfString + 1 ).equals( E[i] ) )
                {
                    emcStringBuffer.append( M[i] + " " );
                }
            }
        }
        emcString = emcStringBuffer.toString();
        System.out.println( emcString );
    }
    else if ( Bool == false )
    {
        for ( SectionOfString = 0; SectionOfString < TextToTranslate.length(); SectionOfString++ )
        {
            if ( TextToTranslate.substring( SectionOfString, SectionOfString + 1 ).equals( space ) )
            {
                for ( i = 0; i < M.length; i++ )
                {
                    if ( MorseCodeLetter.equals( M[i] ) )
                    {
                        mceStringBuffer.append( E[i] );
                        System.out.println( MorseCodeLetter + ";" + mceStringBuffer );
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ( TextToTranslate.substring( SectionOfString, SectionOfString + 1 ).equals( M[36] ) )
                {
                    mceStringBuffer.append( E[36] );
                }
                else
                {
                    MorseCodeLetter.append( TextToTranslate.substring( SectionOfString, SectionOfString + 1 ) );
                }
            }
        }
        mceString = mceStringBuffer.toString();
        System.out.println( mceString );
    }
    System.out.println( "Done" );
}
}
```

The problem seems to be that this part of the code is never used while translating Morse Code into English:

```
if ( TextToTranslate.substring( SectionOfString, SectionOfString + 1 ).equals( space ) )
            {
                for ( i = 0; i < M.length; i++ )
                {
                    if ( MorseCodeLetter.equals( M[i] ) )
                    {
                        mceStringBuffer.append( E[i] );
                        System.out.println( MorseCodeLetter + ";" + mceStringBuffer );
                    }
                }
            }
```

This causes the morse code letters not to be separated. For example, if the input for TextToTranslate was

```
. .-. | .-. .
```

then the program would think that ..-..-. was a word. I'm not sure if this is the reason that the translated result does not print to the terminal ( or command prompt on windows ).

Also, I tried to have space be a static char before, and I just tried having space as a final char, using the following in the if construct, and I had the same problem:

```
TextToTranslate.charAt( SectionOfString ) == space
```

I'm not sure why this problem happens, and I tried to find a similar question but was unable to, so if anyone knows how to fix the problem I would appreciate it.

Note: I asked the same question on Java Programming Forums (user: Indybones33)

Comment: Interesting question, however your decoding procedure does not seem to match Wikipedia's definition of spacing in Morse code... Where does that `|` come from? Is that the equivalent of seven dots?

Comment: Proposal: Use ``TextToTranslate.charAt(SectionOfString) == space`` in your ``if``, which requires the ``space`` to be a ``final char space =  ' ';`` instead.

Answer (score 2):

> This causes the morse code letters not to be separated. For example,
>   if the input for TextToTranslate was
>
> . .-. | .-. . then the program would think that ..-..-. was a word.
>   I'm not sure if this is the reason that the translated result does not
>   print to the terminal ( or command prompt on windows ).

Do you know this? Or are you assuming it? I think you are quite wrong.

I think the real problem is this:

```
if ( MorseCodeLetter.equals( M[i] )
```

This should always return `false` because `MorseCodeLetter` is of type `StringBuffer` and `M[i]` is of type `String`.

You can fix this problem by simply doing this:

```
if ( MorseCodeLetter.toString().equals( M[i] ) )
```

As a side note, using a `StringBuffer` is unnecessarily too complex. You could simply use String concatenation (`String MorseCodeLetter = ""; MorseCodeLetter += letter;`). Also, in general `StringBuffer` is intended for multi-threaded programs and `StringBuilder` is preferred.

Side note 2: All of your notations and naming conventions are not standard Java convention. This means that it is difficult for other Java programmers to easily read your code. Only `class` names should be UpperCamelCase. Variable names (like `MorseCodeLetter` in your code) should be lowerCamelCase.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed part of the problem, so now part of the program is printed to the terminal: 
MorseCode-English
. .-. | .-. .
EF F
Done

Answer (score 0):

I didn't make it through the complexities of the code example, but here is a simple space comparison, just in case this is helpful.

```
String str = "x y";
String strSpace = " ";

if (strSpace.equals(str.substring(1,2))) {
    System.out.println("Bingo");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the same problem occurred after modification.